# How do I add .gif to pathnames in Apache httpd?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is a simple htaccess question for experts but I have been trying to get this sorted for a while. This was something a developer did before my time with this code. He truncated the image file extension from the requests. As an example,

`/images/btn/Find a bear` should get the URL changed internally to `/images/btn/Find a bear.gif`

All the images in the folder are `.gif` extensions.

I tried this URL rewrite at the root folder but it did not help.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ images/$1.gif
```

I know that `RewriteRule` is enabled on the server, etc. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re probably having an infinite loop. Try this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !.*\.gif$
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ images/$1.gif
```